# How can you insert a value in a list as you iterate over that list if a condition is met?

Tags: python, for-loop

Problem; iterate through this list, and wherever you find a 2, mod the list such that you flank it with the flags "Found" and "Target" before and after it.

expected input: l = [1,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,1]
expected output: l = [1,0,1,0,"Found",2,"Target",1,0,"Found",2,"Target",0,1]

seems easy enough?

```
l = [1,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,1]

for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == 2:
        l.insert(i-1,"Found")
        l.insert(i-+,"Target")
```

But this will fail, but illustrates the idea?

I've searched a lot of stack questions and I can't seem to find an elegant solution to this. I feel like I'm also approaching this problem all wrong with the wrong logic, as I believe youre not suppose to change the very list you are iterating over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right... you shouldn't change the very list you are iterating over. So, you need to create two versions of your list... one is the original (`l`) and the other is the original after iteration (`new_l`).

Here is what I mean:

```
l = [1,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,1]
new_l = []

for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == 2:
        new_l.extend(["Found", l[i], "Target"])
    else:
        new_l.append(l[i])
print(new_l)
# [1,0,1,0,"Found",2,"Target",1,0,"Found",2,"Target",0,1]
```

Comment: but, this creates a new list. I think OP asked to modify the list.

Comment: Maybe... but I think all the Original Poster was looking for is the `expected_output`

Answer (score 0):

It's typically a bad idea to change a object while you are iterating over it.

Here it is how I would do this

```
l = [1,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,1]

new_l = []
for el in l:
    if el == 2:
        new_l.extend(["Found", el, "Target"])
    else:
        new_l.append(el)
```

Notice that I'm using the more "pythonic" and efficient approach of iterating over the list instead of using range(len(l)).

The second approach, which I wouldn'd particularly use but it could give you an idea for another time is using list comprhension + itertools.chain.from_iterable (itertools being a standar library package).

```
new_l = (["Found", el, "Target"] if el == 2 else [el] for el in l)
new_l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_l))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to create a new list but just want to modify the first one.

This one uses the same logic as yours, but we have to use a global index to iterate so we don't append at repeated positions, also we can skip the locations which we don't need.

```
l = [1,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,1,2]

print(l)
k = 0
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[k] == 2:
        l.insert(k,"Found")
        l.insert(k+2,"Target")
        k+=3
    else:
        k += 1

print(l)
```

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 'Found', 2, 'Target', 1, 0, 'Found', 2, 'Target', 0, 1, 'Found', 2, 'Target']
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but the complexity of `insert` is `O(m)` where `m` is the index that you're inserting at... so, the worst case scenario for your code will be `O(n**2)`

Comment: Yes, but it's not creating a new list as OP suggested to modify the list.